# Can someone help me understand this Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

I am using the book Elements of the Theory of Computation (2nd edition), which has been fine until now. However, I am stuck trying to grasp the Machine Turing conveyed in Example 4.1.8 (pages 189-190). I cannot make sense of the copying machine portrayed in Figure 4-8. Can someone help me understand with an input word as an example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how I decode this program. The $R_\sqcup$ is a macro for the machine that moves right until it reads a blank. I deduce that $R^2_\sqcup$ repeats this process, locating the second blank to the right. Now the machine shutles right and left moving one non-blank $a$ to the right each cycle.
The position in the original string of the current copied character is temporarily marked with a blank.

```
move-Left until space

step-Right 

while the current character a is not a space
do
    write space // overwriting a, but it is memorized,
    twice: move-Right until space,
    write a       //on the position of the second space
    twice: move-Left until space,
    write a       // restoring the a in the first copy
    step-Right
od

move-Right until space
```